Showing the existence of Nash Equilibrium in a specific partnership game
Suppose there are two players with utilities $u_i(x_1,x_2) = f(x_1)f(x_2) - c(x_i)$ for $i = 1,2$. If $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$, $c : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$ such that both functions are continuous and strictly increasing, $\min\{f(0), c(0)\} > 0$, $f$ is concave and $c$ is convex, show that a Nash Equilibrium exists.
Attempt:

$u_1(x_1, \overline{x_2})$ is convex when $x_2$ is fixed at $\overline{x_2}$. Similarly, $u_2(\overline{x_1}, x_2)$ is also convex.

Since the domain is bonded and the functions are continuous, $x_i^{*} \in \arg\max_{x_i} u_i(x_i, \overline{x_{-i}})$ exists for both.

The set of points $(x_i^{*}, x_{-i}^{*})$ collected from the procedure in (2) gives us the NE points.


Questions:

Is my proof correct?
Did we make use of information such as $f(0)$ and $c(0)$ are positive, and that the functions are strictly increasing?

